# How to use `filter` with multiple iterables, as is supported by `map`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterable

`filter` accepts only one iterable, whereas `map` accepts a variadic number of iterables. For example, I can exhaust `map(operator.add, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4])` to get `[2, 4, 5, 8]`.

I'm looking for a similar mechanism for `filter`, accepting any predicate and a variable number of iterables. Exhausting `filter(operator.eq, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4])` causes a `TypeError` about how `filter` only accepts 1 iterable, not 2.

My expected output for that particular case is `([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4])`, i.e the pairwise elements that don't satisfy `operator.eq` are removed.

Here's what I have so far (eager version supporting only 2 iterables instead of N):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Iterable

A = TypeVar("A")
B = TypeVar("B")

def filter_(predicate: Callable[[A, B], bool], iterable1: Iterable[A], iterable2: Iterable[B]) -> (Iterable[A], Iterable[B]):
    filtered_iterable1 = []
    filtered_iterable2 = []

    for value1, value2 in zip(iterable1, iterable2):
        if predicate(value1, value2):
            filtered_iterable1.append(value1)
            filtered_iterable2.append(value2)

    return filtered_iterable1, filtered_iterable2
```

However my goal is to 1) be able to support N iterables and 2) to have `filter_` be lazy instead of eager, as is with `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def filter_(predicate, *iterables):
    for t in zip(*iterables):
        if predicate(*t):
            yield t

print(list(filter_(operator.eq, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4])))
```

It is lazy, it outputs `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)]` for your test case, and no, you can't have `([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4])` as a result in a lazy way. To convert from `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)]` to `([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4])` you could use: `zip(*filter_(operator.eq, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4]))` but then of course you lose the laziness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you clarify why I can't have a lazy `([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4])`? In other words, why does `zip(*...)` eagerly evaluate each list in the unpacked tuple? I was thinking something like `(<generator>, <generator>)` was possible as the final output.

Comment: No no no, the `zip` **is** lazy. However, your tuple of generators would have to use some sort of a cache. I mean, assuming the call `(x,y) = filter_(operator.eq, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4])` assigns two generators to x and y, you can iterate othem independently, for example exhaust just one of them without even touching the other one - but in the background, this means exhausting the `zip`. Now how the other generator gets its values? You need to store every tuple returned by the `zip` until the other generator is used and reads the stored values. Hence "cache".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no equivalent to `starmap` like `starfilter`, so the equivalent I can think of is:

```
[i for i in zip(*lists) if predicate(*i)]
```

`lists` here being something like `([..], [..])`. This results in:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)]
```

To turn this back into separate lists, use `tuple(map(list, zip(*result)))`:

```
([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4])
```

So, putting it together:

```
predicate = operator.eq
lists = [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4]

result = tuple(map(list, zip(*(i for i in zip(*lists) if predicate(*i)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is in your implementation. Map accepts a function taking multiple lists which must match the number of arguments. Filter takes a single list to filter, so the difference in not just semantic - it makes sense for filter to only take a single list. In your case the list is indeed the `zip`, and that is what you implement. What you are missing is a nifty way to unpair the paired results:

```
>>> r1, r2 = zip(*filter(lambda x: predicate(*x), zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 1, 3, 3, 5)))
>>> r1
(1, 3, 5)
>>> r2
(1, 3, 5)
```